# React Native deep linking does not work when app is killed

Tags: ios, react-native, deep-linking

## Possible solution

I found a solution myself in the meanwhile, probably not so 'clean'.

In App.js I specify my initialRouteName like this:

```
import {createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';

import Home from './screens/Home';
import Form from './screens/Form';
import {Linking, Platform} from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';

function getRoute() {
  let route = "";
  Linking.getInitialURL().then(url => {
    route = url;
  })

  if (route === 'playgroundapp://form') {
    return 'Form';
  } else {
    return "Home"
  }
}

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
    {
  Home: { screen: Home },
  Form: { screen: Form },
}, {
      initialRouteName: getRoute()
    });

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

---

## Question

I want to be able to deep link to my React Native application from my iOS widget.
Linking works fine when the app is running in the background, it navigates to the correct page. But when the app is killed, it only opens the app, but does not navigate to the correct page anymore.

I followed this tutorial: https://medium.com/react-native-training/deep-linking-your-react-native-app-d87c39a1ad5e

With a few adjustments from the official documentation: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking

AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>

#import <React/RCTLinkingManager.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
   openURL:(NSURL *)url
   options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
{
  return [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url options:options];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(nonnull NSUserActivity *)userActivity
 restorationHandler:(nonnull void (^)(NSArray<id<UIUserActivityRestoring>> * _Nullable))restorationHandler
{
 return [RCTLinkingManager application:application
                  continueUserActivity:userActivity
                    restorationHandler:restorationHandler];
}

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}

@end
```

App.js

```
import {createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';

import Home from './screens/Home';
import Form from './screens/Form';

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: Home },
  Form: { screen: Form },
});

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

Home.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import {
  Linking,
  Platform,
  Text,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

import Form from './Form';

export default class Home extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      Linking.getInitialURL().then(url => {
        this.navigate(url);
      });
    } else {
      Linking.addEventListener('url', this.handleOpenURL);
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    Linking.removeEventListener('url', this.handleOpenURL);
  }

  handleOpenURL = event => {
    console.log(event.url)
    this.navigate(event.url);
  };

  navigate = url => {
    const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
    const route = url.replace(/.*?:\/\//g, '');

    const routeName = route.split('/')[0];
    if (routeName === 'form') {
      navigate('Form');
    }
  };

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.h1}>Playground</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

So from my widget I link to the app like this:
`extensionContext?.open(URL(string: "playgroundapp://form")! , completionHandler: nil)`

Why doesn't it work when the app is not running in the background? I found a few similar questions, but no answers that worked for me or which were outdated.

Comment: Anyone found any solution for this ?

Answer (score 2):

If for iOS you have handled `RCTLinkingManager` as below

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
            options:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)options
{
  BOOL handled = [[RNFirebaseLinks instance] application:application openURL:url options:options];

  if(!handled)
  {
    handled = [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url options:options];
  }

  return handled;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray<id<UIUserActivityRestoring>> * _Nullable))restorationHandler
{
  BOOL handled = [[RNFirebaseLinks instance] application:application continueUserActivity:userActivity restorationHandler:restorationHandler];
  if(!handled)
  {
    handled = [RCTLinkingManager application:application continueUserActivity:userActivity restorationHandler:restorationHandler];
  }

  return handled;
}
```

And you have followed the procedure as mentioned at [React Native linking](https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking.html).

```
_dynamicLinkListener; // variable defined to hold listeener instance

 componentDidMount() {
        this.setUpDynamicLink();
        this.setUpDeepLink();
    }

 componentWillUnmount() {
        this.cleanUpDynamicLink();
        this.cleanUpDeepLink();
    }

setUpDynamicLink = () => {
        // will work when link is opening the app
        Firebase.links()
            .getInitialLink()
            .then((url) => {
                this.handleURL(url);
            });

        // listener will work when app is already opened or in background
        this._dynamicLinkListener = Firebase.links().onLink((url) => {
            this.handleURL(url);
        });
    }

setUpDeepLink = () => {
        // will work when link is opening the app
        Linking.getInitialURL().then(url => {
            this.handleURL(url);
        });

        // listener will work when app is already opened or in background
        Linking.addEventListener('url', this.handleURL);
    }

cleanUpDynamicLink = () => {
        this._dynamicLinkListener();
    }

cleanUpDeepLink = () => {
        Linking.removeEventListener('url', this.handleURL);
    }

handleURL = (event) => {
        let url = "";

        if (!event) {
            return "";
        }

        if (typeof event == 'string') {
            url = event;
        } else {
            url = (event.url) ? event.url : "";
        }

        if (!url) {
            return;
        }


        console.debug(url);
    }
```

Then you are good to go. I was getting deep-link callback when the application was in `foreground`, `background` but not in `killed` state.

Disable debugging for your application and use some `Alert` to show `url` instead of using console output. `Linking` has some issue when debugging is enabled. I was able to see url in alert after this.

Code mentioned above also has `Firebase` implementation for dynamic links, which you can remove you dont want it.

Comment: Thank you, stopping debugging fixed it for me

Answer (score 0):

Check with this package.

import dynamicLinks from '@react-native-firebase/dynamic-links';

```
dynamicLinks().getInitialLink()
      .then(link => {
    // this method will call when app is closer or killed
        console.log('dynamicLinksnew :', link);
     
      });

dynamicLinks().onLink(async (link) => {
      // this method call when app is in background or foreground 
     console.log('dynamicLinks :', link);
     
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use react-navigation deep link make sure your debugger turns off. and you can see params with Alert component replace

Answer (score 0):

write config like this.

```
const config = {
  ...config,
  const onReceiveURL = ({ url }: { url: string }) => {
       listener(url);
    };

    // Listen to incoming links from deep linking
    Linking.addEventListener('url', onReceiveURL);

    return () => {
      // Clean up the event listeners
      Linking.removeEventListener('url', onReceiveURL);
    };

}
```